# enable basic auth at api gateway

Tags: express, aws-api-gateway, basic-authentication

I've set up an `express` basic auth using the `express-basic-auth` module.

```
const basicAuthFunc = basicAuth({
    challenge: true,
    users: { 'admin': s.BASIC_AUTH.ADMIN_PASS }
})
```

it works on localhost. I'm prompted with a popup js challenge.

i'm deploying to `lambda` function and using `AWS API gateway`.

the page does not present me with the challange. I just get the `401` directly.
I tried removing the basic auth and the page loads so it's just related to the `basic auth`.

what headers should I add to api gateway ?

tried this one :
https://medium.com/@Da_vidgf/http-basic-auth-with-api-gateway-and-serverless-5ae14ad0a270

adding `WWW-Authenticate` and `'Basic'`  to 401 response.

didn't work[image]